# Dynamically binding a dropdown control's selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a home page , where i have created div's via a `<asp:Repeater.../>` control. Now on the click event on a button in the `<div>` , I am redirecting the page to Registration form where I have a `<asp:DropDown.../>` control .

On `Page_Load` event of the Registration page , I am populating the dropdown from the database and setting `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`.

Now there i am assigning the `EventTypeID` to `dropdown.DataValueField` and `Name` to `dropdown.DataTextField`. I also checked that the dropdown upon rendering contains the `EventTypeID` in the `value` field..

Here is the code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventTypeLogic eventTypeLogic = new EventTypeLogic();
        int eventTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]);

        ddlEventType.DataSource = eventTypeLogic.populateEventTypeDDL();
        ddlEventType.DataValueField = "EventTypeID";
        ddlEventType.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlEventType.DataBind();
        ddlEventType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Event Type", "0"));

        if (eventTypeID > 0)
        {
            ddlEventType.SelectedIndex = eventTypeID;
        }
    }
```

DropDown aspx code :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEventType" runat="server" CssClass="span2 form-info" />
```

Home page code :

```
</p><h6><a class="btn btn-custom" href='<%# "HostEvent.aspx?ID=" + Eval("EventTypeID") %>' ><b>host event</b></a></h6>
```

**Problem :** I want that dropdown should have the value selected before hand, based on the selection on the Home page.

**UPDATE:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventTypeLogic eventTypeLogic = new EventTypeLogic();
        int eventTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]);

        string name = eventTypeLogic.resolveToName(eventTypeID);

        ddlEventType.DataSource = eventTypeLogic.populateEventTypeDDL();
        ddlEventType.DataValueField = "EventTypeID";
        ddlEventType.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlEventType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Event Type", "0"));
        //ddlEventType.DataBind();


        ddlEventType.SelectedIndex = eventTypeID;
        ddlEventType.DataBind();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u want that `EventName` should be displayes as a pre selected value in your `Ddl` than just fire a query with `eventTypeId` and get all information of that event and try this.

```
// i suppose when you fire query you get an Object `EventDetails`
if (eventTypeID > 0)
        {
            ddlEventType.SelectedIndex = eventTypeID;
ddlEventType.SelectedValue = EventDetails.EventTypeID.ToString();
        }
```

this should work!